# Как найти узкое место в программе, влияющее на производительность?

Tags: windows, c++

Понимаю, что слишком общий вопрос, но сделал тестовый снифер по примеру с офф. сайта winpcap и просто повесил его на Qt в отдельный поток. И теперь он может использовать от 5-50% процессорного времени. Есть ли какие-то инструменты, чтобы с ними было проще найти проблему в алгоритме? Профайлеры или что-то ещё.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос. Запускаете профайлер, дергаете разные функции вашей программы, и смотрите, где у вас самые узкие места.

Comment: Профайлера обычно мало. Нужно ещё понимать, что именно он выводит и как это оптимизировать.

Comment: +1, я бы только добавил конкретные решения, к примеру, мой опыт - verysleepy, и он удобен и хорош, кроме того профайлер идет в комплекте к Intel C++. Кроме того, удобен AMD codexl, и в моем GentlementKit/Profilers лежит ApplicationVerifier, но его не помню.